# how to retrieve hashMap data as a list and display in list

Tags: listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am saving date to firebase with HashMap, I watched many tutorials, but facing problem in getting that data into list and display as List. Any help please thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much you are gonna traversal hashMap and add the useful data in to a arrayList

Comment: or the right and easy way ? is send data with creating model class and retrieve wtih same modle class?

Comment: actually ,is ok for any kind of data source ,see the abstract method in BaseAdapter, we should do getItem () ,getCount() ,getView(),getItemId.

Comment: just make it as ArrayList,is easy to do , because each position of ArrayList corresponding each position of ListView or GridView.both of them is orded

Comment: and please one more thing.... the method 'Firebasechildeventlistener' is used to retrieve or send tha data? or for both

Comment: I am so sorry ~I forgot that

Comment: In my country ,we can't use google, so we don't use firebase a lot..:(

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem i recomand you iterate your `Map`. You can achieve this using this code:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.child("yourChild").getValue();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    list.add(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}

for(String s : list) {
    Log.d("TAG", s);
}
```

Hope it helps.